# What is the source for untying things before going under the chuppah?

Tags: minhag, sources-mekorot, wedding, tying-knots-kosheir

At a wedding recently I saw that the grooms shoes were untied, someone explained to me that there is a custom to make sure there are no knots under the chuppah. Where does this come from?

Comment: http://thehalacha.com/wp-content/uploads/Vol4Issue12.pdf

Comment: http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46545&st=&pgnum=117

Answer (score 4):

According to [this article:](http://www.jewish-history.com/minhag.htm)

> Before the chuppah all the knots on the groom's garments are untied.
>   This symbolizes that at the moment of marriage all other bonds are
>   eliminated, except this intimate one made between the bride and groom.

Apparently, this may be a Hassidic custom? I haven't seen any weddings where I have seen this done. Then, again, I assume that the chattan has done this prior to walking down the aisle, and I'm not exactly looking at the chattan's pants or shoes. A number of chattanim, including myself, wore slip-ons. I think one wore crocks (a bit weird, I guess, but, there was probably a med reason for that.)

So, according to this view, the chattan, who often davens under the chuppah, can't wear a gartel???

Comment: The gartel is tied in a way that doesn't require a knot.

Comment: At my very non-Chassidish chasuna, the mesader kiddushin had me untie the knot of my tie (even though it was a slipknot!)

Answer (score 2):

According to [this shuir](http://vimeo.com/6494459)(starting at 16:30) from Rav Shachter, quoting Rav Soleveitchik, this is not a minhag based on anything (minhag shtus).

Answer (score 1):

Rav Moshe Heinemann explains in [*Mah Nomar Shidduchim - Sheva Berachos*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0851KBW2H) (6:8):

> The Torah writes when you lend someone money and want to take
> collateral to ensure payment, “לֹא יַחֲבֹל רֵחַיִם וָרָכֶב כִּי נֶפֶשׁ
> הוּא חֹבֵל” (Devarim 24:6) don’t take the grinding stone which he uses
> to grind the wheat since he needs it for his פרנסה either as a job or
> for food. That’s poshut pshat. The Targum Yonasan ben Uziel (Devarim
> 24:6) says לֹא יַחֲבֹל  refers to not tying up a chosson or kallah
> because רֵחַיִם means the woman and the רָכֶב is a משל to the man.
> There’s a certain kishuf you can do to prevent the chosson and kallah
> from being נזקק with one another, so the Torah says a special איסור
> beyond kishuf to not tie up the chosson and kallah. However, there are
> two things the chosson and kallah can do to ensure the kishuf doesn’t
> work. The first thing they can do is not have any knots. The second
> עצה is for the chosson to put gold in his pocket. For this reason, the
> minhag was to give the chosson a golden watch, often a pocket watch,
> so he could put the gold in his pocket to prevent this kishuf from
> taking effect. I’ve never heard of anyone who knows how to do this
> kishuf today, so we don’t really have anything to worry about. They
> don’t have to untie all the knots, and if they do then they’ll have
> some problems with the button sewed onto the jacket which likely have
> knots on the end of the thread. If it makes you happy to untie all the
> knots, then you can do it, but you don’t have to do so.

Answer (score 0):

As [DanF cited](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/47822/21), there appears to be a Hassidic custom about "no bonds are as strong as this one." I don't know the source on that, but here's a theory.

There's a slightly more prevalent custom for the chasan to remove any jewelry he's wearing before going under the chupa. This could easily be explained by the nuts-and-bolts halacha that the kiddushin would be voided if based on a false premise. If she thought "I'm only marrying him because he's rich [see, he's covered in bling]", or "wow, he's giving me that ring plus all that bling he's wearing!"], we could have halachic issues.

Thus my *guess* is the practice went from:

- *"Make clear if you're wearing bling that she knows what you're really worth, and what you're actually giving her"*

To:

- *Take off the bling.*

To:

- *He and she should take off the bling. Or anything blingy. Eh, even cufflinks or chains.*

To:

- *Just untie everything.*

To:

- *Oh, what a beautiful custom! We do it to show that no bond is stronger than marriage!*

(Someone who had the no-jewelry custom had asked the German-born Rabbi Shimon Schwab, proper gentleman that he was, about removing his cufflinks under the chupah. *What, and look like a shlepper?! Of course not!* [Then again, in that culture, the bride would never have a remote dream that he'd be caught removing his cufflinks in public to give her.])